# ReflectionException in Route.php line

Tags: php, laravel

```
<?php 
class Myform  extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('form');
    }
}
?>
```

the code of routes

```
Route::get('/myform', 'Myform@ndex');
```

and the error is

> ReflectionException in Route.php line 264: Method
>   App\Http\Controllers\Myform::ndex() does not exist

Comment: Typo, change to: `Route::get('/myform', 'Myform@index');` You are missing an "i"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change from

```
Route::get('/myform', 'Myform@ndex');
```

to

```
Route::get('/myform', 'Myform@index');
```

Answer (score 1):

You did a typing mistake index instead of ndex

```
Route::get('/myform', 'Myform@index');
```

instead

```
Route::get('/myform', 'Myform@ndex');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `/` before `myform`, you don't need to put it.

Declare the route as follows: `Route::get('myform', 'Myform@index');`

In your controller file add `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` at the top of your code.

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class Myform  extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('form');
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this will work.